# Locate offset of peak value for three sines of different period and amplitude.

Tags: trigonometry

I am combining three sines of different frequencies and amplitudes to produce an output wave for a given length of time. The time is less than twice the period of the lowest frequency. I need to find the time offset to the point where the combination wave has its highest positive peak.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. What do you think needs to be done? How would you start off? By writing which equations? You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an edit): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: When up to three sines of different amplitude and not widely different frequencies are added, assuming a given starting time and running time, is there a simple computation that will predict when the combined profile will be at its maximum positive value during that time?